# How to create a new folder?

Tags: java, scala

Or more specifically, how to create a new folder with a random name in scala?

In Java the code was this:

```
  val folderPath: Path = Paths.get("src/test/resources/test-documents/")
  val tmpDir: Path = Files.createTempDirectory(folderPath, null)
```

thanks to all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The same calls will work in Scala. All of the Java APIs are interoperable.

Comment: But the question is how to do it using Scala, not Java.

Answer (score 4):

Generally Java code work fine in Scala environment if the java class files include properly.

```
import java.nio.file.{Path, Paths, Files}

val folderPath: Path = Paths.get("src/test/resources/test-documents/")
var tmpDir: Path = Files.createTempDirectory(folderPath, null)
```

This code works fine in scala to create new temp directory.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it seemed strange that does not work.
The problem is that I expected the folder were created at one point and instead was created at root level, and rightly so.

Sorry!